# Can you access a Virtual Directory outside of an ASP.NET website?

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-directory

Can you access a Virtual Directory outside of an ASP.NET site?

For example,  in a Console application?

Comment: Do you mean an IIS virtual directory? Doesn't this console app run outside of the IIS environment? Can you give a little more info?

Comment: Yes, I mean an IIS virtual directory.  Sorry I didn't specify.

Comment: @lubos, what is strange about it?  I have a need to access a directory across one server to another.  I can do this easily inside say, an ASP.NET site.  However, if I also have other applications which need to do the same, such as some console application, how is it supposed to be able to gain access to that same directory ?

Comment: You need to tell us what you are trying to do in order to receive an effective answer.  This question is far too broad and there is not enough detail.

Answer (score 0):

I would configure ftp folder under iis which is pointing to that mentioned directory and then using ftp protocol and windows or active directory user give some application access rights to it. Dose it solve youre issue? By using ftp connection you can do anything you want in that directory by any program you want. Of course as long as this program is able to use frp protocol. Or insted of it you can log remotly to that host using microsoft tool named psexec and run for exzample some but on you target host. There are many possibiliteis.
You can find some ready and usefull code in C# or vb.net which is implementing ftp client on google.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head..Have you already looked into [System.DirectoryServices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.aspx) namespace for this. That should also include reading/writing virtual directories. Let me know If this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm confused on what you mean by "access"? Are you trying to access the:

1. physical files that are stored in the Virtual Directory (Ftp/UNC/Webdav access via file services)
2. Virtual Directory with a view to manage it and change its properties (using the Microsoft.Web.Administration assembly)
3. data that the Virtual Directory presents (Web services/Scraping etc.)

I think you need to be a little clearer with your question if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

We use mapped drives and permissions setup on the App Pool for the application to access other directories on other servers.